# control over the text colors in an ioslides presentation

Tags: r, r-markdown, ioslides

I am preparing an ioslides presentation. For reasons out of my control, all the text on the title slide needs to be white, and all the subsequent slides need to have white titles. The following CSS fixes everything except the text color for the author and date.

```
slides > slide.title-slide hgroup h1,
slides > slide hgroup h2,
slides > slide.title-slide hgroup .author, 
slides > slide.title-slide hgroup .date {
    color: white;
}
```

In general, where are all these css classes and labels documented? I try to find these things out by rendering my slides and viewing the source HTML, but not everything is made clear.

Comment: Where do the classes .author and .date come from? I don't have them when inspecting the slides in my browser...

Comment: Now there, I am just guessing. I did not actually find any CSS selectors for the author or date.

Comment: Well guessing is not that useful in such a case ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Author and date are contained inside common p tags.
Use this:

```
<style>
slides > slide.title-slide p {
  color: red;
}
</style>
```

Comment: where can you add the above code? I suppose it cannot simply be added to the top of .rmd file

Comment: You can put css code into a css chunk. `-```{css echo=FALSE} ...```-`

Comment: How do you alter the title?

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar concerns about the lack of documentation. I found helpful these slides: https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/27777_55697c3a476640caa0ad2099fe914ae5.html#/1

Another possibility, I think, for identifying the labels for your html file, is to use Selector Gadget: http://selectorgadget.com

Using Selector Gadget may be easier than reading the html code yourself.

I hope that this helps.

Comment: I will try Selector Gadget. It sounds like something that would meet my needs.